# Need to decompress .z file (weird deflate)

Tags: c#, zlib

So, I have a .z file which I need to decompress. I tried all known methods (I think) but still nothing.

I also have some libraries which could *possibly* help to decompress this file.
(the .z file and libraries are from the game).  Here you can get .zip archive with .z file and libraries.
[Download](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2wXEaIcyofbWlkzOU9zZE94aDA)

I really want this to be solved, so I'm ready to give as much information as I can, so you can ask me.

Comment: .z file compression is used in Terry Davis's OS called TempleOS, but I doubt that you have this from that OS :)

Comment: Open the file in a hex editor and look at the fist bytes. Usually files start with " magic header" that can be used to identify the file format. This is more precise than the (changeable) file extension.

Comment: @Robert As Mark said, it is zlib file and not image, audio etc.

Answer (score 1):

The songs.z file starts with a valid two-byte zlib header. However what follows is not a valid deflate stream, and there are no valid deflate streams within of any significant length (i.e. it is what you would expect to find in random data). It does appear to be compressed data, in that the histogram of bytes is relatively flat. Though the bytes at the very end have a lot of `f`'s, which would be suspicious if those were the expected check value at the end. That's all that I can determine.